Riverpod VSCode quick refactoring options are absent
Hello Please help with Riverpod.
Everything works on the  command line (Code generation, etc)
But VSCode quick refactoring options are absent.
I have analysis_options.yaml with :
analyzer:
plugins:
custom_lint
I followed all the installation pages from the official documentation.
should I install some plugins or something?
Code asistant has no more ideas.

Try this recipe again:

Add all the required dependencies to pubspec.yaml. In the simplest case, this is:

dependencies:
  flutter_riverpod:

dev_dependencies:
  riverpod_lint:
  custom_lint:

and
flutter pub get


Next we add to analysis_options.yaml:

analyzer:
  plugins:
    - custom_lint

custom_lint:
  # To check, we forcefully enable all the rules
  enable_all_lint_rules: true


If the custom lint is still not displayed, try activating it manually via:

dart run custom_lint

or
# install `custom_lint` for all projects
dart pub global activate custom_lint
# and run `custom_lint`'s command line in a project
custom_lint


Restart IDE


If these steps do not help, also try these commands:

flutter clear --> flutter pub get
ctrl + shift + p --> Dart: Restart Analysis Server
ctrl + shift + p --> Dart: Reanalyze Dart Sources

If all else fails, write an issue in the repository Issues · invertase/dart_custom_lint.
